# nGen EXE +DLLs through Setup and Deployment project

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0, setup-deployment, ngen

I have this code that *should* nGen my main application EXE:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Configuration.Install;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace FileOnline.DesktopClient.Setup.Support {
    [RunInstaller(true)]
    public partial class CustomNGen : Installer {

        public override void Install(IDictionary stateSaver) {
            base.Install(stateSaver);
            ExecuteNGen("install", true);
        }

        public override void Uninstall(IDictionary savedState) {
            base.Uninstall(savedState);
            //CleanUpShortcuts();
            ExecuteNGen("uninstall", false);
        }

        private void ExecuteNGen(string cmd, bool validate) {
            var ngenStr = Path.Combine(RuntimeEnvironment.GetRuntimeDirectory(), "ngen");
            var assemblyPath = Context.Parameters["assemblypath"];

            using (var process = new Process {
                StartInfo = {
                    FileName = ngenStr,
                    Arguments = string.Format(@"{0} ""{1}""", cmd, assemblyPath),
                    CreateNoWindow = true,
                    UseShellExecute = false
                }
            }) {
                process.Start();
                process.WaitForExit();

                if (validate && process.ExitCode != 0)
                    throw new Exception(String.Format("Ngen exit code: {0}", process.ExitCode));
            }
        }

    }

}
```

What I require is that not only the EXE be nGen'd, but all the referenced DLLs (my whole solution) also get nGen'd

Say my EXE project is called:

```
FileOnline.DesktopClient
```

And it depends on these:

```
FileOnline.DesktopClient.BaseControls
FileOnline.DesktopClient.BaseForms
FileOnline.DesktopClient.Utilities
FileOnline.DesktopClient.Dialogboxes
FileOnline.DesktopClient.HelpingExtension
FileOnline.DesktopClient.*More stuff*
```

How can I nGen these through the only deployment project in the solution?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is automatic, ngen.exe finds those assemblies through Assembly.GetReferencedAssemblies().  You'd only have to take care of assemblies you load yourself with Assembly.Load/From().  Review the /execonfig option if you have unusual binding rules in the .exe.config file, ngen.exe needs to know those too so it can find the proper assembly.

Alternative methods are [here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/ngen) and [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/clrcodegeneration/archive/2010/04/27/ngen-creating-setup-projects.aspx).